# Scrapy Reverse Crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

The spider crawls some specific links from one page. It then searches in each of those pages a youtube link and a name to identify it to(the page title). It does find all the links I need however the order is odd.

The spider gathers all the page information from bottom to top. How can I make it go from top to bottom?

My Spider: http://pastebin.com/5qLKr6ky

Output: http://pastebin.com/j4h4aRMs

Start page: It is in the spider( I can't post more than 2 links because I'm a new user)

I want the output to be in the same order as in the start page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know scrapy, but I know that you can reverse a list or other iterable in python quite simply with a call to [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed).

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I need. The list is not just reversed. There are many links that are in random order and I don't know why. It's hard to explain, but if you can look at the Output it becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you mean that you need resulting Youtube links in order in which they placed on start page?

Links are in random order because Scrapy makes requests in parallel

```
class ProfessormesserSpider(BaseSpider):

    allowed_domains = ['www.professormesser.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.professormesser.com/n10-005/free-network-plus/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract urls from start page and REMEMBER THEIR ORDER(!!!)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for i, link in enumerate(hxs.xpath("//td[@valign='center']/div/descendant::a/@href")):
            # "i" is the link's order
            yield yield Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'i': i})

    def parse_item(self, request):
        order = response.request.meta["i"]
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page source for one of the linked pages, it includes links to the previous and next videos. These links are of this form:

```
<div class="entry clearfix">
...
<b>Next:</b> The TCP/IP Model  &gt;&gt;</a><br />
<center><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lSK1d8fZyEw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center></p>
</div>
```

As a consequence, you're picking up duplicate entries (albeit with differing links). You may need to develop a more explicit xpath that filters out these other links.